# Multithreaded Non-Blocking-IO Selector

Tags: java, nio

Has Non-blocking server, now it looks like:

```
ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
// ... Many stuff like initialise selector, load world, etc
while(server.isOpen())
{
    selector.select();
    Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
        switch(key.interestOps())
        {
            case SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT:
                // .... Accepting, register selector, packet handler etc
                break;
            case SelectionKey.OP_READ:
                // .... Read-write stuff
                break;
        }
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

I need to e.g. 1 thread handles 100 connections. Other 100 connections handles another thread. I tried do it with this code:

```
public class ConnectionsHandler implements Runnable
{
    private Selector selector;// For each thread gets its own selector

    @Override public void run()
    {
        while(Server.server.isOpen())
        {
            selector.select();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
                // .... Read-write stuff
                iterator.remove()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But both threads after first accepted connection freezes... No any exception thrown, it's simply freezes.

Comment: It is invalid to use a switch statement. A key can be both readable and writable at the same time.

Comment: But i don't register selector with OP writeable =) SocketChannel is always writeable, and key can't be both readable and acceptable.

Comment: No, SocketChannel is not always writeable. Usually. Not always. You can't write a correct NIO program without using OP_WRITE.

Comment: Okay, moved write stuff to OP_WRITE. But with OP_WRITE server again eats 40% of CPU! Code:
http://pastebin.com/EydBx5zM
http://pastebin.com/yLXszcVv
http://pastebin.com/wSxyLnC7
http://pastebin.com/3yVqzN4t

Comment: It's not that simple. You only need to select for OP_WRUTE after you had had a zero length write, which means the send buffer is full. As I said above, this is usually not the case, and OP_WRITE is usually ready. So selecting for it all the time is always going to fire.

Comment: Many, many, many thanks! Solved problem with OP_WRITE, now i set it only if i has any data to write :) Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

register() is a blocking operation and so is select(). If getMostFreeSelector() returns the other selector and it is in select() at the time, the register() will block until the selector wakes up. You could call selector.wakeup() to fix this, or always register to the current selector, but I would question the whole architecture. Unless you have many thousands of connections there is little point in the second selector and thread.

Note also my comment above about the switch statement.

Comment: where i need call selector.wakeup()? after processing selectors, or before register?

Comment: Before register(). It's the *other* selector you want to wakeup, not your own.